# Android Samsung phone stops broadcastreceiver from getting updates randomly

Tags: android, gps, samsung-mobile

I can't seem to figure this one out.  I have a broadcastReceiver that is registered in the manifest.  I ping for gps once a minute, the broadcastReceiver's onReceive fires and starts a service.  This service grabs a wakelock just in case, sends the GPS Coords to our server using an ASyncTask and releases the wakelock, and calls stopSelf(). This fires consistantly on my Nexus 6p and an HTC.

However on a Samsung GS5, this only works for so long.  The time it stops seems random but usually within 30 mins, sometimes as short as 5 mins.  The broadcastReceiver never gets called again, meaning the onReceive just stops firing.

All power saving settings on the samsung are turned off that I can notice.  Unless there is a super tricky hidden one, I can't figure out how the Samsung phone can stop this broadcastReceiver, or stop GPS, whichever is happening.

This happens even if the app is not swiped closed.  The phone goes idle, screen turns off, and about 5-30 mins later, the phone stops getting coords.

This happens whether I use GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER although with network provider it seems to happen even faster.

Here is where I start the GPS.

```
public void startBackgroundGPS () {

    Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();

    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, LocationReceiver.class);
    int status = context.getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(component);
    Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(status));
    if(status == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED || status == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT) {
        Log.d(TAG, "receiver is enabled");
        //getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    } else if(status == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "receiver is disabled");
        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("myBroadcast");
    intent.putExtra("session_id", session_id);
    intent.putExtra("device_id", device_id);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 58534, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Register for broadcast intents
    locationManager  = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, pendingIntent);

}
```

Here is my broadcastReceiver

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//private static boolean semaphore = true;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("DistanceFilterLocationService", intent.getAction());


    Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);

    Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(context, DistanceFilterLocationService.class);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("device_id", intent.getStringExtra("device_id"));
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("session_id", intent.getStringExtra("session_id"));

     Double longi = location.getLongitude();
     Double lati = location.getLatitude();
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("longitude", longi);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("latitude", lati);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("accuracy", location.getAccuracy());
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("time", location.getTime());
    context.startService(locationServiceIntent);
}
}
```

Here is my broadcastreceiver in the manifest.

```
<receiver android:name="com.mypackage.LocationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Anyone run into something like this?  Found a couple similar questions but no answers were given.  This one is killing me as it completely destroys the purpose of the app on Samsung phones.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a good answer, but perhaps the android version could be the problem. Or, maybe some addons from Samsung... did you test on other Samsung phone (maybe another android version)?